# Join table data duplicate in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created two tables **busbook** and **seats**. When I join two tables data duplicated I don't why.

```
SELECT seats.busno,
       seats.seats,
       busbook.status,
       busbook.customer,
       busbook.mobile,
       seats.date
FROM seats
     Left JOIN busbook ON  seats.busno=busbook.busno
```

This is an output I got:

```
busno  seats     status     customer         mobile    date
91000     1       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     2       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     3       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     4       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     5       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     6       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     7       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     8       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000     9       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
91000    10       Booked     ss              11      2019-12-06
```

**seats** table:

```
id    busno   seats       date
1     91000    1      2019-12-06
2     91000    2      2019-12-06
3     91000    3      2019-12-06
4     91000    4      2019-12-06
5     91000    5      2019-12-06
6     91000    6      2019-12-06
7    91000     7      2019-12-06
8    91000     8      2019-12-06
9    91000     9      2019-12-06
10   91000    10      2019-12-06
11   91000     11     2019-12-06
12   91000     12     2019-12-06
```

**busbook** table:

```
id  busno   seat     status       customer       mobile        date
2   91000    1       Booked          ss            11          2019-12-06
3   91000    19      Booked          dd            22          2019-12-06
```

Comment: *"data duplicated i don't why"* There are no duplicates in your data; every row is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT seats.busno, seats.seats,busbook.status, busbook.customer,busbook.mobile,seats.date FROM seats 
Left JOIN busbook ON seats.busno=busbook.busno
AND seats.seats = busbook.seat
```

I guess it depends on what exactly scheme is to do join by seats.id or seats.seats

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get require result:

```
SELECT seats.busno,
       seats.seats,
       busbook.status,
       busbook.customer,
       busbook.mobile,
       seats.date
FROM seats
 JOIN busbook ON seats.busno = busbook.busno AND seats.seats = busbook.seat
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s.busno, s.seats, s.status, 
       b.customer, b.mobile, s.date 
FROM seats s
INNER JOIN busbook b ON s.busno=b.busno AND s.seats = b.seats

The requirements are not very clear from your question, and your question is at risk of being downvoted.

But in the interest of solving your problem. This is the query you most probably need.

You have used the LEFT JOIN keyword

But the The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

What you want to use is The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.

Also your query has multiple mistakes at the join ON condition. I have rectified it, Hope this solves your problem.