# Two column records shown as null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined two tables `busbook` and `seats`. But two column records shown as null in mysql customer, mobile columns as null.

`busbook` table:

```
id   busno  seat  customer   mobile     date
----------------------------------------------------
12   91000    2   ss         11111      2019-12-06
13   91000    3   saaaaa     2222       2019-12-06
```

`seats` table:

```
id    busno  seats  date         status
-------------------------------------------
29    91000    1    2019-12-06   Booked
30    91000    2    2019-12-06   Booked
31    91000    3    2019-12-06   Booked
32    91000    4    2019-12-06   Booked
33    91000    5    2019-12-06   unbooked
34    91000    6    2019-12-06   unbooked
35    91000    7    2019-12-06   unbooked
36    91000    8    2019-12-06   unbooked
37    91000    9    2019-12-06   unbooked
```

```sql
SELECT 
    seats.busno, seats.seats, seats.status, 
    busbook.customer, busbook.mobile, seats.date 
FROM
    seats 
LEFT JOIN 
    busbook ON seats.busno = busbook.busno AND seats.id = busbook.seat
```

Result is being returned like this:

```
 busno  seats  status   customer  mobile   date
 -----------------------------------------------------
 91000    1    Booked   NULL      NULL     2019-12-06
 91000    2    Booked   NULL      NULL     2019-12-06
 91000    3    Booked   NULL      NULL     2019-12-06
 91000    4    Booked   NULL      NULL     2019-12-06
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to display customer, mobile data  to the colums

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join table data duplicate in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211817/join-table-data-duplicate-in-mysql)

Comment: If the `seat` and `seats` are supposed to store same type of data, they should have the same name. Is it _seat number_, or _number of seats_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the ON clause:

```
...AND seats.id = busbook.seat
```

is probably wrong.
Maybe you need:

```
...AND seats.seats = busbook.seat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.busno, s.seats, s.status, 
       b.customer, b.mobile, s.date 
FROM seats s
INNER JOIN busbook b ON s.busno=b.busno AND s.seats = b.seats
```

The requirements are not very clear from your question, and your question is at risk of being downvoted.

But in the interest of solving your problem. This is the query you most probably need.

You have used the `LEFT JOIN` keyword

But the The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is `NULL` from the right side, if there is no match.

What you want to use is The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.

Also your query has multiple mistakes at the join `ON` condition. I have rectified it, Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @alberto thanks for formatting the answer, however you made no changes to the actual contents of the answer

Comment: I didn't change the context because what you wrote is correct. I have improved the readability of the code and therefore of the response

Comment: If you think what I have written is correct an upvote will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`AND seats.seats = busbook.seat` instead of `AND seats.id = busbook.seat`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your join condition like this

```
AND seats.seats = busbook.seat
```